# Update column with select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello I would like to set a table column I tried with the update query but I have syntax error

```
  $cmts="UPDATE stat_alert INNER  JOIN cell_cmt  ON stat_alert.cell = cell_cmt.cell SET stat_alert.`cmts` = cell_cmt.`Cmts`";
$cmt= mysql_query($cmts)OR DIE("Erreur sur la requete");
```

I have erreur sur la requete 
who can help me

Comment: (In English) the OP states that he gets _Error in the request_.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code: you have en error of syntax because from gone before the set. Set have to be after the inner join

```
UPDATE stat_alert a 
INNER  JOIN cell_cmt b ON a.cell = b.cell
SET a.`cmts` = b.`Cmts`
```

Comment: Query: UPDATE stat_alert FROM stat_alert INNER JOIN cell_cmt ON stat_alert.cell = cell_cmt.cell SET stat_alert.`cmts` = cell_cmt.`Cmts`...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM stat_alert 
INNER  JOIN cell_cmt 
ON stat_alert.cell = cell_cmt.cell
SET 
 ' at line 2

Comment: there should be no `FROM` keyword.

Comment: thanks @John Woo I have edit my answer with another code and now it works fine, tested on my webserver!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right syntax for `UPDATE` with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE stat_alert
INNER  JOIN cell_cmt ON stat_alert.cell = cell_cmt.cell
SET 
  stat_alert.`cmts` = cell_cmt.`Cmts`
```

The mysql  [**`UPDATE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) dictates that the table references `stat_alert 
    INNER  JOIN cell_cmt ON stat_alert.cell = cell_cmt.cell` comes after the `UPDATE` clause directly. Thats what you was missing.

Comment: Query: UPDATE stat_alert FROM stat_alert INNER JOIN cell_cmt ON stat_alert.cell = cell_cmt.cell SET stat_alert.`cmts` = cell_cmt.`Cmts`...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM stat_alert 
INNER  JOIN cell_cmt ON stat_alert.cell = cell_cmt.cell
SET 
  ' at line 2

Comment: demand SQLyog is right but it's not  works when I put this query in php error  request

Comment: @user1794019 - Please update your question with the php code you are using to execute this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using version of `UPDATE with JOIN` in MSSQL, In `MYSQL`, it should be like this, (***FROM*** keyword shouldn't be specified)

```
UPDATE stat_alert a 
       INNER  JOIN cell_cmt b
          ON a.cell = b.cell
SET a.`cmts` = b.`Cmts`
```

- [**SOURCE**](http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html)

Comment: $cmts="UPDATE stat_alert INNER  JOIN cell_cmt  ON stat_alert.cell = cell_cmt.cell SET stat_alert.`cmts` = cell_cmt.`Cmts`";
$cmt= mysql_query($cmts)OR DIE("Erreur sur la requete"); error but its works in sqlyog :(